# How can I show only 3 countries in country list (select box)?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm using [SMS User](http://drupal.org/project/smsframework) module which validates users' mobile numbers. There's a select box and all countries in it. Users select country and write their mobile numbers.

I want to show only 3 countries in it, but there's no option in admin panel. I looked up the **sms_user** table. There is a gateway column and country codes writing. That's all.

How can I modify the country list? When I looked into the module code, I found nothing about countries.

Comment: You can use `hook_form_alter()` and unset the rest of the values.

Comment: thanks, but sms_user module in here sites/all/modules/smsframework/modules/sms_user and in sms_user.info project name is smsframework and also the module sms_clickatell in sites/all/modules/sms_clickatell so i add in template.php this lines to check.

Comment: 1-function sms_clickatell_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'sms-user-settings-add-form') {
    // Rename the submit button
    $form['submit']['#value'] = t("Save");
  }
  }

Comment: function smsframework_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'sms-user-settings-add-form') {
    // Rename the submit button
    $form['submit']['#value'] = t("Save");
  }
  }

Comment: After i clear cahches but nothing change. i want to modify select box option but firstly i test if submit value changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to shorten the country select box in user registration form and user edit form. You should not hack the contributed modules. You could create your own module and override the forms using [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

I assume you have a custom module and you could implement hook_form_alter() to update the country list as you need. Here is the code in mymodule.module tested in my test site:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if( $form_id == 'user_register_form' || $form_id == 'user_profile_form' ){
        $countries = array( // define the countries you want
            93  => 'Afghanistan', 
            355 => 'Albania', 
            213 => 'Algeria'
        );
        $form['sms_user']['gateway']['country']['#options'] = $countries; // update sms country select box.
    }
}
```

But, to access the field group **sms_user**, your module must have the heaviest weight, otherwise you won't be able to update `$form['sms_user']['gateway']['country']`.
You can make sure your module is heaviest by creating `yourmodulename.install`.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_install()
 */
function mymodule_install(){
    # Fetch max module weight from "system" table.
    $max_weight = db_query("SELECT MAX(weight) FROM {system} WHERE type = 'module'")->fetchField();
    # Make sure this module is the heaviest one in order to run last
    db_update('system')
        ->fields(array('weight' => $max_weight+1))
        ->condition('name', 'mymodule')
        ->execute();
}
/**
 * Implementation of hook_uninstall()
 */
function mymodule_uninstall(){
    db_delete('system')
        ->condition('name', 'mymodule')
        ->execute();    
}
```

If you are expert, you can tweak the `weight` field of your module in the `system` table to make it heaviest without creating `yourmodulename.install`, but not recommended. You may need to flush all caches after you implemented this.

Comment: thanks, i solve my problem another way and your answer help me.